# Got wrong values at report after changing the evaluation time from Report to Auto

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a JasperReports's report displaying 2 columns col1, col2

The report must display

```
col1  col2
d1    abc
d2    def
d3    ghi
```

I the code looked good and tested both in server and in web. It worked well.

Recently, we got a bug from the customer saying the data was displayed as below

```
col1 col2
  d1   abc
  d2   abc
  d3   abc
```

I deleted $F{col2} and re-added it. And the report started working fine again

When I look at the *jrxml* the only difference I see is, *the evaluation time changed from Report to Auto*

Can anybody explain this strange behaviour?

Comment: It appears you have us at a disadvantage. While *you* can see the JRXML, *we* cannot. Perhaps level the playing field by posting the JRXML file so we can help? :-)

Comment: Fields should be evaluated "NOW", but since no jrxml we can't really know what your expression is anyway auto should only be used when you need to combine different values at different time, so change back to "NOW"

Answer (score 0):

Evaluation time is an interesting feature of *JasperReports* engine. The icing on the cake.

Let's look at Java code. We need the *net.sf.jasperreports.engine.type.EvaluationTimeEnum* class.

```java
public enum EvaluationTimeEnum implements JREnum {
    /**
     * A constant specifying that an expression should be evaluated at the exact moment in the filling process
     * when it is encountered.
     */
    NOW((byte)1, "Now"),

    /**
     * A constant specifying that an expression should be evaluated at the end of the filling process.
     */
    REPORT((byte)2, "Report"),

    /**
     * A constant specifying that an expression should be evaluated after each page is filled.
     */
    PAGE((byte)3, "Page"),

    /**
     * A constant specifying that an expression should be evaluated after each column is filled.
     */
    COLUMN((byte)4, "Column"),

    /**
     * A constant specifying that an expression should be evaluated after each group break.
     */
    GROUP((byte)5, "Group"),

    /**
     * The element will be evaluated at band end.
     */
    BAND((byte)6, "Band"),

    /**
     * Evaluation time indicating that each variable participating in the expression
     * should be evaluated at a time decided by the engine.
     * <p/>
     * Variables will be evaluated at a time corresponding to their reset type.
     * Fields are evaluated "now", i.e. at the time the band the element lies on gets filled.
     * <p/>
     * This evaluation type should be used when report elements having expressions that combine 
     * values evaluated at different times are required (e.g. percentage out of a total).
     * <p/>
     * NB: avoid using this evaluation type when other types suffice as it can lead
     * to performance loss.
     */
    AUTO((byte)7, "Auto"),

    /**
     * Used for elements that are evaluated at the moment the master report ends.
     * 
     * @see JRVariable#MASTER_CURRENT_PAGE
     * @see JRVariable#MASTER_TOTAL_PAGES
     */
    MASTER((byte) 8, "Master");
```

It is a well done description of all types of *Evaluation Time*.

In case we set ***Report*** evaluation time - the result will be the repeated last record from the datasource.

### Example

We can check different types of evaluation time with small sample.

#### Template

We can use the *JRBeanCollectionDataSource* for test purpose.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Check evaluation time" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
    <subDataset name="ds">
        <field name="value" class="java.lang.String">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[_THIS]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
    </subDataset>
    <summary>
        <band height="15">
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="311" height="15"/>
                <jr:list xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd" printOrder="Vertical">
                    <datasetRun subDataset="ds">
                        <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource(Arrays.asList("abc", "def", "ghi"))]]></dataSourceExpression>
                    </datasetRun>
                    <jr:listContents height="15" width="311">
                        <textField evaluationTime="Report">
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="311" height="15"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{value}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </jr:listContents>
                </jr:list>
            </componentElement>
        </band>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

#### Output result

The generated result with help of *JRPdfExporter* looks like:

- evaluationTime="Report"

[image: Result for Report evaluationTime]

- we have 3 rows with the same values. It is a last value from our dataset repeated 3 times.

- evaluationTime="Auto"

[image: Result for Auto evaluationTime]

- we have all 3 different rows from our original dataset.

#### Conclusion

In case using ***Auto*** evaluation time for our sample we should read this part of description:
`Fields are evaluated "now", i.e. at the time the band the element lies on gets filled`.

It means that this time (for this basic case) the *JasperReports* engine applied the simple stradegy - the full analog of ***Now*** evaluation time.

It will be better to remove *evaluationTime* for this *textField* or set it as `evaluationTime="Now"` (it is a default value of *evaluationTime*).

Comment: Thanks a lot. Well understood!!